# Converting a matrix to its components

Tags: c++, performance

I'm working in a very large project and in this post I'll share only the function that I feel it could be written in better way.

I have a function called `M44toM33` with quite many declarations, variables and repeated operations.. What do you think about this function? could be better?

I'm quite open and flexible for any suggestions (I can use other library or don't use any library opencv for eg.)

Here's the function, just copy and paste the program and you can execute it in your machine:

> g++ -g -Wall -Weffc++ -Ofast -march=native test.cpp -o test `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`

The code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp> 

void M44toM33(const cv::Mat& M_in, float& qx, float& qy, float& qz, float& qw, float& tx, float& ty, float& tz);

int main()
{ 
    cv::Mat M=cv::Mat::zeros(4,4, CV_32FC1);

    //some values to test the function
    M.at<float>(0, 0)=0.844499;
    M.at<float>(0, 1)=-0.433715;
    M.at<float>(0, 2)=-0.314185;

    M.at<float>(1, 0)=-0.314918;
    M.at<float>(1, 1)=-0.876663;
    M.at<float>(1, 2)=0.363714;

    M.at<float>(2, 0)=-0.433183;
    M.at<float>(2, 1)=-0.208214;
    M.at<float>(2, 2)=-0.876926;

    M.at<float>(3, 0)= 0;
    M.at<float>(3, 1)= 0;
    M.at<float>(3, 2)= 1;

    M.at<float>(0, 3)=0.632352;
    M.at<float>(1, 3)=-0.461493;
    M.at<float>(2, 3)=1.06753;


    float qx, qy, qz, qw, tx, ty, tz;
    M44toM33(M, qx, qy, qz, qw, tx, ty, tz);

    // Those are the values I shoud get 0.632352 -0.461493 1.06753 -0.150756 0.948431 -0.197335 -0.197001
    std::cout << " " << tx << " " << ty << " " << tz << " " << qx << " " << qy << " " << qz << " "<< qw << std::endl;

    /*
    do stuff with t and q
    */

}


void M44toM33(const cv::Mat& M_in, float& qx, float& qy, float& qz, float& qw, float& tx,

                                             float& ty, float& tz)

{
    auto SIGN=[](float x)
    {
        return (x >= 0.0f) ? +1.0f : -1.0f;
    };

    auto NORM=[](double a, double b, double c, double d)
    {
        return sqrt(a * a + b * b + c * c + d * d);
    };

    assert(M_in.total() == 16);

    cv::Mat M;

    M_in.convertTo(M, CV_32F);

    // use now eigen
    float r11 = M.at<float>(0, 0);
    float r12 = M.at<float>(0, 1);
    float r13 = M.at<float>(0, 2);
    float r21 = M.at<float>(1, 0);
    float r22 = M.at<float>(1, 1);
    float r23 = M.at<float>(1, 2);
    float r31 = M.at<float>(2, 0);
    float r32 = M.at<float>(2, 1);
    float r33 = M.at<float>(2, 2);

    double q0 = (r11 + r22 + r33 + 1.0f) / 4.0f;
    double q1 = (r11 - r22 - r33 + 1.0f) / 4.0f;
    double q2 = (-r11 + r22 - r33 + 1.0f) / 4.0f;
    double q3 = (-r11 - r22 + r33 + 1.0f) / 4.0f;

    if (q0 < 0.0f)
        q0 = 0.0f;

    if (q1 < 0.0f)
        q1 = 0.0f;

    if (q2 < 0.0f)
        q2 = 0.0f;

    if (q3 < 0.0f)
        q3 = 0.0f;

    q0 = sqrt(q0);
    q1 = sqrt(q1);
    q2 = sqrt(q2);
    q3 = sqrt(q3);

    if (q0 >= q1 && q0 >= q2 && q0 >= q3)
    {
        q0 *= +1.0f;
        q1 *= SIGN(r32 - r23);
        q2 *= SIGN(r13 - r31);
        q3 *= SIGN(r21 - r12);
    }

    else if (q1 >= q0 && q1 >= q2 && q1 >= q3)
    {
        q0 *= SIGN(r32 - r23);
        q1 *= +1.0f;
        q2 *= SIGN(r21 + r12);
        q3 *= SIGN(r13 + r31);
    }

    else if (q2 >= q0 && q2 >= q1 && q2 >= q3)
    {
        q0 *= SIGN(r13 - r31);
        q1 *= SIGN(r21 + r12);
        q2 *= +1.0f;
        q3 *= SIGN(r32 + r23);
    }

    else if (q3 >= q0 && q3 >= q1 && q3 >= q2)
    {
        q0 *= SIGN(r21 - r12);
        q1 *= SIGN(r31 + r13);
        q2 *= SIGN(r32 + r23);
        q3 *= +1.0f;

    }

    double r = NORM(q0, q1, q2, q3);
    qx = static_cast<float>(q0 / r);
    qy = static_cast<float>(q1 / r);
    qz = static_cast<float>(q2 / r);
    qw = static_cast<float>(q3 / r);

    tx = M.at<float>(0, 3);
    ty = M.at<float>(1, 3);
    tz = M.at<float>(2, 3);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward and fairly easy to read. That's great! Here are some other things that I noticed:

## Naming

I would name this function differently. The name implies that it's converting a 4x4 matrix to a 3x3 matrix, but it returns 7 `float`s instead of a matrix. I would name it something like `Matrix44ToMatrix33Components()`, or something similar, so it's clear what's coming back.

## Making the Code Shorter

You say:

> I have a function called `M44toM33` with quite many declarations

You could remove the lambda for `SIGN` and use `std::sign()`, though it might have performance implications. And since `NORM` is just a single call to `sqrt`, I'd just replace the one call to `NORM` with a call to `std::sqrt()`.

Additionally, you could use `std::min()` to replace the comparisons with 0. This:

```
if (q0 < 0.0f)
    q0 = 0.0f;

if (q1 < 0.0f)
    q1 = 0.0f;

if (q2 < 0.0f)
    q2 = 0.0f;

if (q3 < 0.0f)
    q3 = 0.0f;
```

becomes:

```
q0 = std::min(q0, 0.0f);
q1 = std::min(q1, 0.0f);
q2 = std::min(q2, 0.0f);
q3 = std::min(q3, 0.0f);
```

Or if that would affect performance you could use the standard C macro `MIN`, which is basically an inline version of your comparisons. Just be aware of [the pitfalls of C macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041453/why-are-preprocessor-macros-evil-and-what-are-the-alternatives#14041847) if you go that route. Chances are the `std::min()` call will be inlined, just profile or check the assembly output to be sure.

## Performance

The best way to know what to optimize is to measure it. I assume you've done that and this function showed up near the top of the list of things that are taking the most time. I would look at specifically which parts of it are taking time.

At a glance, I see that you're doing a lot of type conversions. I've seen that be a performance issue in the past, so it might be one here. (Again, measure to be sure.) If so, I would see if you can avoid converting the input matrix to a different type and just use values from the input matrix directly. In fact, it might be worth making everything `double` instead of `float` just to avoid the conversions. But if you don't, I'd question the need for the `q0` - `q3` and `r` values to be `double` when you're just going to convert them back to `float` in the end.

Another way to speed this up is to use an existing library that's been highly optimized and debugged through years of use by other people. Off the top of my head, there's [LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/), [BLAS](http://www.netlib.org/blas/), [BOOST](http://www.boost.org), and [glm](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.8/index.html) which all have matrix operations. I don't know whether each of them has every bit of functionality you need, though.

Some other ways to speed this up include parallelizing the code. Matrix operations are often a good candidate for using SIMD extensions like SSE, AVX, NEON, etc. You might benefit from those. Additionally, if you are doing many of these sorts of operations, you might benefit from having multiple threads running the calculations on multiple pieces of data at the same time. In fact, this function could be used as-is, but called on multiple threads at once, if your data and operations are set up properly.

Comment: I have never seen `std::min` not being inlined. Using the C macro `MIN` is not recommended because it evaluates one of the operands twice.

Comment: Nor have I. But I haven't tested every implementation!  In general I do not like C macros for exactly that reason. In this code it wouldn't be a problem, and I would only recommend it if it's performance critical and for some reason `std::min` wasn't getting inlined. I'll add a note to that effect.